# Projection matrix p onto subspace S

Tags: matrices

Suppose that $S$ is the subspace in ${\mathbb R}^4$ spanned by the two vectors
    $$
 {\bf a}_1=\begin{bmatrix}
 3 \\ 1 \\ -2 \\ 1 
 \end{bmatrix}, \;
 {\bf a}_2=\begin{bmatrix}
 2 \\ -1 \\ 3 \\ 5 
 \end{bmatrix}.
 $$
     a.Find the projection matrix $P$ onto $S$.

b.Find the projection ${\bf p}$ of ${\bf b}$ onto $S$ where
        $$ {\bf b} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  5 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\1
  \end{bmatrix}.
  $$
        c.If ${\bf b}$ is in $S$ then what is $P{\bf b}$?

d.If ${\bf b}$ is in $S^\perp$ then what is $P{\bf b}$?

I found the projection matrix P, but currently stuck on b. When it asks find the projection p of b onto S, should I just simply multiply the projection matrix P with b? If so, then how should I answer c and d. I review hard on my notes and online videos, but haven't found any useful idea for these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for part (b) you just multiply $b$ by the projection matrix from the left. For part (c), observe that if the vector is in the subspace, its projection is just itself. For part (d), if your vector is perpendicular to $S$, its projection is just the zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

You should add two important properties of orthogonal projections to your notes. I’m rather surprised that these haven’t come up anywhere in the material that you’ve been studying.

- A projection is the identity map on its own range. That is, if $P$ is a projection onto $S$ and $\mathbf b\in S$, then $P\mathbf b=\mathbf b$. This is true of all projections, not just the orthogonal ones that you’re working with here.
- The kernel of an orthogonal projection $P$ onto $S$ is $S^\perp$, i.e., if $\mathbf b\in S^\perp$, then $P\mathbf b=0$. You can view $P$ as splitting a vector $\mathbf b$ into components $\mathbf b_\parallel\in S$ and $\mathbf b_\perp = \mathbf b-\mathbf b_\parallel\in S^\perp$, and then returning $\mathbf b_\parallel$. If $\mathbf b\in S^\perp$ so that $\mathbf b-\mathbf b_\perp=0$, then $P\mathbf b = \mathbf b_\parallel$ must be $0$.

This sort of parallel/orthogonal decomposition will come up again when you study reflections.